# How to disable auto instrumentation of a library but only for metrics and keep traces

Tags: java, open-telemetry, open-telemetry-java

When using OpenTelemetry Java agent, we get many libraries auto instrumented.

It's possible to disable a library instrumentation with `OTEL_INSTRUMENTATION_[NAME]_ENABLED` but this disables all sorts of instrumentation: metrics and traces for instance.

**Is there a way to disable a library instrumentation for only for some "scope" like only disable metrics but keep traces?**

Or is the only way out of this to implement some filtering later (in OpenTelemetry collector for instance if using it)?

---

The concrete use case for this is that I'm using Akka HTTP in my application and I do want to collect its traces, but I really don't care about its metrics (there's a label with the route which makes it have a huge cardinality moreover).

Comment: high cardinality of akka http metrics sounds like a bug, can you report an issue with more details at https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/issues

Comment: @trask I opened a [discussion](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/discussions/9959), not sure it's necessarily a bug